# How to easily switch gcloud / kubectl credentials

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, kubectl

At work we use Kubernetes hosted in GCP. I also have a side project hosted in my *personal* GCP account using Google App Engine (deploy using `gcloud app deploy`).

Often when I try to run a command such as `kubectl logs -f service-name`, I get an error like "Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "my_personal_email@gmail.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "WORK_NAMESPACE": Required "container.pods.list" permission." and then I have to fight with kubectl for hours trying to get it to work.

Can somebody please break it down for a slow person like me, how `gcloud` and `kubectl` work together, and how I can easily switch accounts so I can use `gcloud` commands for my personal projects and `kubectl` commands for my work projects? I'm happy to nuke my whole config and start from scratch if that's what it takes. I've found various `kubectl` and `gcloud` documentation but it doesn't make much sense or talks in circles.

Edit: this is on Linux.

Comment: Which operating system. Why not create two different logins and then switch terminal windows (if on Linux). For Windows, move your setup to batch scripts and open different Command Prompts for each environment. The first step is to define commands that correctly set up each environment. You should not have to struggle for hours to switch.

Comment: Have a gander at this post that I wrote. There are various ways that you can address your need: https://medium.com/google-cloud/context-light-gcloud-and-kubectl-89185d38ce82

Comment: Two other features with kubectl : you can create multiple configs and then set `KUBECONFIG` per environment; you can include namespaces in contexts so you may not only default to a specific cluster and auth pair but a default namespace too.

Comment: This one too on how `gcloud` works with `kubectl`: https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-engine-kubectl-config-b6270d2b656c

Answer (score 19):

Had the same problem and doing all of the:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud auth list
gcloud config set account
gcloud projects list
```

didn't help. I knew `gcloud` switched fine as I was able to list other resources with it directly.
But it seems `kubectl` can't pick those changes up automatically, as `kubectl/gcloud` integration relies on the pre-generated key, which has a 1h expiration(not sure if it's a default but it's what it is on my machine right now).
So, on top of setting right user/project/account with `gcloud`, you should re-generate the creds:

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials <my-cluster> --zone <clusters-zone>`

Comment: The last line is key, that's what will force kubectl to use the new cluster

Answer (score 7):

### TL;DR

Edit: Kubernetes 1.26 has a change relating to this answer, now use `gcloud auth` to manage your different profiles.

1. Use `gcloud auth` to manage your separate profiles with the Google Cloud Platform.
2. Add an **explicit** account to use when requesting a token with the `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` to your kubectl config file (`~/.kube/config`) to teach kubectl to use a specific account with a certain cluster rather than your active account.

```yaml
# file: ~/.kube/config
users:
- name: gke_project-name_cluster-zone_cluster-name
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
      args:
      - --account=your@work.email # <<< Add this line
```

---

> Can somebody please break it down for a slow person like me, how gcloud and kubectl work together, and how I can easily switch accounts so I can use gcloud commands for my personal projects and kubectl commands for my work projects?

Sure! By following Google's suggested instructions that lead to running `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...` when configuring a kubernetes cluster, you will end up with a section of your kubeconfig that contains information on what kubectl should do to acquire an access token when communicating with a cluster that is configured with a given user. That will look something like this:

```yaml
users:
- name: gke_project-name_cluster-zone_cluster-name
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args: null
      command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
      env: null
      installHint: Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following
        https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: true
```

Basically, this tells `kubectl` to run `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` when it needs a new token, and that the access token can be parsed from the output of that command. **This is the crux in understanding how `kubectl` communicates with `gcloud`**.

Like you, I use google cloud both personally and at work. The issue is that this user configuration block does not take into account the fact that it *shouldn't* use the currently active gcloud account when generating a credential. Even if you don't use kubernetes in either one of your two projects, extensions in vscode for example might try to run a kubectl command when you're working on something in a different project. If this were to happen after your current token is expired, `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` might get invoked to generate a token using a personal account.

To prevent this from happening, I suggest using `gcloud config configuations`. Configurations are global configuration profiles that you can quickly switch between. They can store more than just account information, any `gcloud config ...` can be saved. For example, I have two configurations that look like this:

```
> gcloud config configurations list                                               

NAME      IS_ACTIVE  ACCOUNT             PROJECT            COMPUTE_DEFAULT_ZONE       COMPUTE_DEFAULT_REGION
work      False      zev@work.email      work-project       us-west1-a                 us-west1
personal  True       zev@personal.email  personal-project   northamerica-northeast1-a  northamerica-northeast1
```

When setting up multiple configurations, you will have to run `gcloud auth login` with your separate accounts. We just need to instruct kubectl to use a specific account to talk to a given cluster, rather than whichever is active.

So then it boils down to this: *if you set up your kubeconfig to execute `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --acount=your@work.email` whenever kubectl needs a new access token for your personal cluster, it will use the account from your work configuration regardless of which account is currently active with the `gcloud` tool*. That would then look like this:

```yaml
# file: ~/.kube/config
users:
- name: gke_project-name_cluster-zone_cluster-name
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1

      # ----- Remove this ------
      args: null
      # -------------------------
      # +++++ Then add this: ++++
      args:
      - --account=your@work.email
      # +++++++++++++++++++++++++

      command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
      env: null
      installHint: Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following
        https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: true
```

Prior to Kubernetes 1.26, the process is the same, except you would use a `gcloud config configuration` directly, rather than an account, so:

1. Use `gcloud config configurations` to manage your separate profiles with Google Cloud Platform.
2. Find the `cmd-args` of your kubeconfig's user, then add an explicit `--configuration` argument to prevent `gcloud` from producing an access token for an unrelated profile.

   ```yaml
   # file: ~/.kube/config
   users:
   - user:
       auth-provider:
         config:
           # !! Prior to GKE 1.26
           cmd-args: config --configuration=work config-helper --format=json
   ```

Comment: The location of the token & the expiry details have changed to `code ~/.kube/gke_gcloud_auth_plugin_cache` if you have upgraded the kubectl, gcloud & use gcloud_auth_plugin to authenticate. So now, you need to set the expiry in the past there.

Comment: @priyesh.patel, Not sure what you're trying to point out. That has nothing to do with my answer, the whole point with this setup is that you don't need to be mucking about with these tokens or their expiry dates.

Comment: To add, by contrast, when using awscli's equivalent populate-kubeconfig command it does similar except, in the context entry, it _also_ sets an env entry of `AWS_PROFILE=yourprofile`, which is why the awscli equivalent of this command works.

Answer (score 3):

For me updating the ~/.kube/config and setting the expiry to a date in past fixes it

Comment: The location of the token & the expiry details have changed to code ~/.kube/gke_gcloud_auth_plugin_cache if you have upgraded the kubectl, gcloud & use gcloud_auth_plugin to authenticate. So now, you need to set the expiry in the past there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same boat as you - apps deployed in GKE for work and personal projects deployed in my personal GCP account.

`gcloud` stores a list of logged in accounts that you can switch between to communicate with associated projects. Take a look at these commands:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud auth list
gcloud config set account
gcloud projects list
```

To work with a specific project under one of your accounts you need to set that configuration via `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`

`kubectl` has a list of "contexts" on your local machine in `~/.kube/config`. Your current context is the cluster you want to run commands against - similar to the active account/project in `gcloud`.

Unlike `gcloud` these are cluster specific and store info on cluster endpoint, default namespaces, the current context, etc. You can have contexts from GCP, AWS, on-prem...anywhere you have a cluster. We have different clusters for dev, qa, and prod (thus different contexts) and switch between them a ton. Take a look at the [kubectx project][1] https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx for an easier way to switch between contexts and namespaces.

`kubectl` will use the keys from whatever GCP account you are logged in with against the cluster that is set as your current context. i.e., from your error above, if your active account for `gcloud` is your personal but try to list pods from a cluster at work you will get an error. You either need to set the active account/project for `gcloud` to your work email or change the `kubectl` context to a cluster that is hosted in your personal GCP account/project.